# Akka cluster sharding spanning multiple projects (sbt)

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have a question about akka cluster sharding:

I have 3 Nodes

2 Nodes with Role - AppServer

1 Node with Role - WebServer

Webserver gets api call from outside 
The WebReception Actor running in node (port id 567), has to send message to Account (With Shard name - Account) running in 2 Nodes

For the above scenario to work, the Node (portID: 567) has to start a Shard of type Account (otherwise it gives an error - Shard type [Account] must be started first)

What if WebReception and Account are in different projects (A and B)? Webrecption (in project A) will have to use the sharding information about Account in project B in order to perform the communication right?
I will upload and image to explain this question.

[image]

Comment: Its been fixed by the usage of - val accountRegion = ClusterSharding(context.system).startProxy(...) in project A. So Project a starts a Proxy not the actual Shard.